# Rails link_to for destroy action: How to pass parameters, data confirmation action and instyle css

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, link-to

```
<%= link_to "[Delete]", customer_path(customer.id, :customer_delete => true), :method => :delete, :data => {:confirm => "Are You Sure?"} %>
```

**My above code working fine,**

**But how to give my link_to a color say ike red in my view ?** Tried many stack overflow threads but couldn't find a solution as my link_to contains a combine functionality like data confirmation action with passing parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**To give color property to Link**

**1. new link with css class**

```
<%= link_to "[Delete]", customer_path(customer.id, :customer_delete => true), :method => :delete, :data => {:confirm => "Are You Sure?"}, :class => 'link' %>
```

**application.css**

```
.link {
  color: red;
}
```

**2. new link with inline css style**

```
<%= link_to "[Delete]", customer_path(customer.id, :customer_delete => true), :method => :delete, :data => {:confirm => "Are You Sure?"}, :style => 'color: red;' %>
```

Comment: Is there a way to give it inline for the link_to without using class ?

Comment: Yes definitely, try this:

Comment: <%= link_to "[Delete]", customer_path(customer.id, :customer_delete => true), :method => :delete, :data => {:confirm => "Are You Sure?"}, :style => 'color: red;' %>

Comment: Btw, what parameters are you talking about that you want to pass through?

Comment: :customer_delete => true this is the extra parameter :) you didn't notice it ? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104711/discussion-between-praveen-george-and-julian-guterman).

Comment: Oh I thought you meant a param that you hadn't added yet. I'm not sure if you're able to pass through a parameter like that through a delete method. I only say that because I have no idea where you'd store it.